# Which cmake property should hold privately linked shared libraries for imported targets?

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, target

Consider importing a target with `find_package( foo REQUIRED )` that provides a shared library. Target foo itself depends on another shared library bar.dll, which is only used in its implementation and not visible in its headers. But as a client of foo I also have to deploy bar.dll in order to run my code.

So which property of the imported target foo should give me the information that I also have to deploy bar?

Should it be in `LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES`, `IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES`, `LINK_LIBRARIES`, `IMPORTED_LINK_DEPENDENT_LIBRARIES` or something else?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Q1. INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES. Q2. None of the above for a modern CMake configuration, especially with Config mode `find_package()`. This is mostly transparent to consumers (as in they don't need to know the names of individual properties), if the library author correctly uses the `target_*` style commands, e.g. `target_link_libraries()` in the original targets being imported. So, why do you ask or can you be more specific about your question?

Comment: **Motivation1:** I imported an external package and now I want to know which .dlls I need to run my code. Often when using an IDE I will need to provide external shared libraries within the build-tree so I can hit F5 and debug my application. **Motivation 2:** I myself want to provide package foo and want to know which properties I should set that clients will find my dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're on a "modern" version of cmake (3.anything), then you are looking for [`IMPORTED_LINK_DEPENDENT_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LINK_DEPENDENT_LIBRARIES.html).

[`LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES.html) and [`IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES.html) are both deprecated, so don't consider them.

[`LINK_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/LINK_LIBRARIES.html) is for building a target; since you're importing a library with `find_package`, it shouldn't be of much use.

[`INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES.html), on an imported target, tells you which libraries are dependencies in the interface (visible in the headers).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think you forgot something in your second sentence. It makes no sence and I would like to know why I should not consider them.

Comment: ... and so I have. Thanks for pointing it out. Fixing it now.